# Javascript Input Paste registers as Undefined

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

I am currently writing a function that writes a bit of code for me based on an input. I am currently working on creating the input and the code that pastes the input, but whenever it writes, it shows up as undefined. This is the code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Javascript YAML Generator</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="yamlform" action="index.html" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="appname" value="Name">
      <button type="submit" onclick="writeAppName()">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var appname = document.getElementsByName("appname").value
    function writeAppName() {
      document.write(appname)
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

NOTE: This is not my final version of the code, at the moment I just want a system for writing an input value that I can duplicate. Final version will be using document.getElementbyID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementsByName` returns colection. Use document.getElementsByName("appname")[0].value.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Javascript YAML Generator</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="yamlform" action="index.html" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="appname" value="Name">
      <button type="submit" onclick="writeAppName()">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var appname = document.getElementsByName("appname")[0].value
    function writeAppName() {
      document.write(appname)
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @xC00L But it is better to add id on input and use document.getElementById("input-id");

Comment: Ok. Another question: I created a variable called appnamelocation that grabs the ID of a div using document.getElementByID. How would I put that variable as the location for the document to write to? Sorry if it is a really simple question, I am new to javascript and haven't really had any uses for it until now.

Comment: @xC00L Sorry  I am new to English. Give an example of the code.

Comment: Thats ok! First I made `var appnamelocation = document.getElementByID('appnameSpace')` then I have in my HTML `<div id='appnameSpace'>` now how do i get the elementbyid to be where `document.write` goes to

Comment: Add me to Skype Smiranin007. And continue to communicate there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer to the first element with name "appname", because it could be a collection. Also I but the assignment for appanme variable inside of the function, this will make it so appname isn't being assigned to "Name" right away and is instead assigned to whatever is in the text box when you click the botton

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Javascript YAML Generator</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="yamlform" action="index.html" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="appname" value="Name">
      <button type="submit" onclick="writeAppName()">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function writeAppName() {
    var appname = document.getElementsByName("appname")[0].value
      document.write(appname)
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `document.getElementsByName`

It is possible that multiple elements would have same name.

While using `document.getElementsByName`, there might be multiple elements instead of a single element present in DOM with similar name, so `document.getElementsByName` returns an array (a list of elements) and not a single element

To use different elements of the Array, use

```
document.getElementsByName("appname")[0]  // For first element with name 
document.getElementsByName("appname")[1]  // For second element with name 
// and so on
```

So in your code, you would use

```
var appname = document.getElementsByName("appname")[0].value;
```

Comment: Ok. I was confused on why people were telling me to use [0] but now I understand. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @xC00L I am glad you got it :)